# Laravel crsftoken routing

Tags: laravel-4, routes

I have some troubles with the `crsf_token()` in laravel. I create a URL to send to the user with the token and if they click this unique link the post will set the token to NULL.

Here my sample code:

```
//get token from database
$getDataUserToken = $subject->lists('token');

// send the token to email user (unique token)
@foreach ($token as $toke){{ URL::to('/extend/verify', array($toke)) }}@endforeach
```

This code will generate: `www.example.com/extend/verify/1234123TOKENHERE2313213123`

Now I want if user clicks on this link that the token sets to null.

I tried this:

```
Route::get('/extend/verify/{$toke}', 'SubjectController@confirm');
```

But when I do this I get an error that says: `throw new NotFoundHttpException;`

So the url is not found and I don't know how to get that url token and send it to my controller to do some stuff with that.

Comment: This has nothing to do with `crsf_token()`. Is your `$toke` using route binding at all? What is in your `confirm()` function?

Answer (score 0):

the laravel route parameters not use "$".
this is a correct use:

```
Route::get('/extend/verify/{toke}', 'SubjectController@confirm');
```